# What library to link to for std::filesystem with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++17, libc++, std-filesystem

Xcode 10.2 now includes the `<filesystem>` header. However, when writing code using `std::filesystem`, I'm running into a lot of extra link errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::__filename() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::filename() const in dump_zip.cpp.o
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::filename() const in libxp_parse.a(zipped.cpp.o)
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::remove_filename() in libxp_parse.a(zipped.cpp.o)
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::has_filename() const in libxp_parse.a(zipped.cpp.o)
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::has_filename() const in libxp_parse.a(acf.cpp.o)
```

I believe an extra library needs to be linked for filesystem support, but I can't identify what or where it is. Any idea what it is called?

EDIT: libc++ says that `libc++fs` is required- however, that doesn't seem to be distributed with Xcode, at least not in the default search directories.

Comment: At the point of writing this question, XCode 10.2 is not publicly released. If the library is missing, then it's likely to be a bug, so file a radar.

Answer (score 11):

Xcode 10.2 does not contain the library support to implement `<filesystem>`. The reason why it was not included in Xcode 10.2 is that the implementation of `<filesystem>` did not have a stable ABI at the time.

So the behavior is expected, however it would be nicer if the error was more explicit about why this happens.

**EDIT: As of Xcode 11 and MacOS 10.15, `<filesystem>` is shipped in the main libc++.dylib and there's no need to link any additional library.**